# MVC favicon.ico routing for WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, favicon

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC/WebAPI project using .NET Framework 4.6.2. In my solution I have different favicon images for each environment (DEV, Staging, PROD). When a MVC page is displayed I am able to point the browser to the correct favicon for that environment without issue. However, any API GET calls done directly from a web browser, it always default to favicon.ico at the site root. Is there anyway to make it route to a configurable value so that I can choose which one will be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that via middleware.  Just make sure the `UseMiddleware<YourCustomMiddlware>` in the Startup.cs `Configure` method comes before `UseStaticFiles()`.  That way it will get an oppertunity to intercept the request and respond to it before the regular static file middleware does.

In your custom middleware you just need to check the url of the request and if it's for the fav icon at the root, then you can check whether you are running in Dev, Staging or PROD and return the actual file you want for the file you are in.

Comment: This would work but I was hoping it could be done by mapping a route. If it turns out that this is not possible, I will mark this as the answer. Either way you get +1 for the answer.

Comment: That would be cool if there was a way to do it via route mapping.  I don't know how to do it via route mapping if it is possible.  Hopefully someone else will chime in if it can be accomplished that way.